# Two different page numbers in Word 2007 (one starting at 1, the other at VI)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, page-numbers

I have a document (docA) with arabic page numbers in the header. Now docA is part of a thesis  which has roman numbers in the footer.

So I want to add roman page numbers to docA. This is no problem. But now I want to adjust the numbering of the roman numbers (as the thesis has lets say five pages). This is what I want:

- arabic page numbers in the header, starting at `1`
- roman page numbers in the footer, starting at `VI`

I tried this:
I choosed 'Page Number', 'Page Number Format' and tried to adjust the starting point. However, this changes both page numbers.

How is it possible to have different numbering in the header and in the footer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using field codes.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to toggle displaying the field code and the calculated value. You'll notice that when you insert a page number, it's actually `{ PAGE }`.

Note that the curly braces `{ }` can't be typed, they must be inserted using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

What we need to do is use a formula. You want to offset the number by 5, so you want something like:

```
{ = { PAGE } + 5 \*ROMAN }
```

To insert this:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> twice to get `{ { } }`
2. Type `PAGE` inside the inner braces
3. Type the `=` between the first two (opening) braces
4. Type `+ 5 \*ROMAN` between the last two (closing) braces
5. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to view the result

---

**Explanation**:

The `=` denotes a [formula field](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-formula-field-HP005186218.aspx). It's similar to an Excel formula, though a little more basic.

The `{ PAGE }` inserts the current page number into the formula - the inner field is calculated first. If you were on the first page, the formula field would see something like `{ = 1 + 5 \*ROMAN }`. If `PAGE` were not denoted as a field code by enclosing it in braces, you insert the text `PAGE` into the formula field which interprets that as a *bookmark*.

The addition should be obvious.

The `\*` specifies the displayed format. `ROMAN` means upper case Roman numerals, `roman` means lower case Roman numerals. It defaults to Arabic numerals if you don't specify a format.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Works perfect. Sorry, I can't upvote your answer, as I have not enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Thanks, but now I would also like to refer to those pages in the table of contents

Comment: __If you need to start numbering from a certain page on__, insert a section break before and then, while editing your header/footer, clear `Link to Previous` in the `navigation` section and `Different First Page` in the `Options` section of the `Header & Footer Tools` ribbon

Answer (score 1):

I'm on MS Word 2007 in Windows XP.

I was going for this in my headers:

```
Page 4 = Folio 1
Page 5 = Folio 2
```

etc

After struggling with the code above (very useful starting point – thanks Bob) as minuses worked but obviously minused (and double minuses made no difference), pluses refused to work and gave syntax errors, and with no operator at all my "Page" numbers kept going into minus territory until they reversed – very odd, I eventually got it right with this as the code for the number following "Page":

```
    { = { PAGE \*ARABIC } + 3 }
```

My final header looks like this:

```
    Page { = { PAGE \*ARABIC } + 3 } = Folio { = { PAGE \*ARABIC \*MERGEFORMAT }
```

I still don't know what the heck mergeformat does but I have other things to worry about now...